# Getting the Color of the Lips using face API

Tags: face, face-api

The Face API gives coordinates of the lips but can we specifically get the color of the lips?

Answer (score 0):

There's one property that you might find useful: `faceAttributes.makeup.lipMakeup`. But, it's just a boolean. You get it by adding `makeup` to the `returnFaceAttributes` parameters.

Comment: I looked at that but, it does not help me find a specific color

Comment: Well if you know the coordinates of the lip you can pretty much get the colour yourself I guess.